# Where could I learn more about automatic reference counting in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I've been looking all over the net for an explanation of the implementation but I haven't found anything. It's also really weird because I can't find **any** academic papers about it either.

So, besides the LLVM source code, where should I look for more information?

The only helpful links I've found are:

- [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [LLVM's official    documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#general)

Comment: The Clang doc and source are pretty much as good as you're going to get... reference counting is a general thing, but ARC is tied really tightly to Cocoa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lack of academic papers about *Apple's* automatic reference counting is unfortunately not "really weird" - it is a commercial implementation of a long known technique.

There are papers and textbooks which cover reference counting as one of the kinds of garbage collection; for example it is covered in the 2nd edition of the famous *Dragon Book*, [*Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools*,  Alfred V. Aho, Monica S. Lam, Ravi Sethi, and Jeffrey D. Ullman, 2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). That books credits [*A method for overlapping and erasure of lists*, Collins, 1960](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=367487.367501&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE) with reference counting. For a web-based summary you could start with [*Reference Counting*, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), this includes references to some papers.

Apple's implementation is not substantially different from others. In some ways it could be argued to be inferior as it does not handle cycles automatically (see the Wikipedia article for some references on cycle detection) for Objective-C or Swift; or it could be argued it provides an efficient balance between automation and manual intervention. Your second reference, [*Automatic Reference Counting*, Clang Documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), is probably the most "formal" description from Apple; and of course the Clang source is available...

HTH